# Change the titleformat of ‘Appendices’

Tags: sectioning, formatting, appendices, parts

I am using the [appendix](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/appendix) package with the `toc` and `page` package options in the following way.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\begin{appendices}
\chapter{Here is an Appendix}
\end{appendices}
\end{document}
```

The `page` package option puts a title (‘Appendices’) into  the document at the point where the appendices environment is begun. It is based on the `\part` definition.

Now I want to change the format of the title ‘Appendices’ (size, capitals or bold or italics, maybe something fancier). I know how to do this for `\part` via `\titleformat{\part}` and if I do it, I can see how the format of the  `\part` heading changes. Unforunately, the format of the title ‘Appendices’ always stays the same.

My questions are:

Is there a way to change the titleformat of the title ‘Appendices’?

Is there a way to force the title ‘Appendices’ to have the same titleformat as the `\part` heading?

Comment: It seems to be formatted as a part. What would you like to change?

Comment: I would like to change the size (for example `\huge`) and I would like to use `\scshape` instead of bold.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The appendix page formatting is not obtained as `\part` but with the special `\@chap@pppage` command, which can easily be patched with `xpatch`. Here is an example with a coloured  `Appendix`, in boldface smallcaps. The font size used by the `appendix` package is `\Huge`

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\@chap@pppage}{%
 \bfseries}{%
 \bfseries\scshape\color{IndianRed!70}}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\part{ First Part}
\chapter{A Unique Chapter}
\lipsum

\begin{appendices}
\chapter{Here is an Appendix}
\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

[image]

*Edit*:

To remove the page number from this page, as the above command includes a `\thispagestyle{plain}}`, you just have to add this code (between `makeatletter` and `makeatother`):

```
\xpatchcmd{\@chap@pppage}{plain}{empty}{}{}
```

Comment: Why do I get the error "Font shape `T1/lmr/bx/sc` undefined(Font) using `T1/lmr/bx/n` instead"?

Comment: Probably because my code uses `cmsuper`. I'm not sure `lmodern` has a bold small caps font.

Comment: If I delete the second `\bfseries`, then it perfectly works.

Comment: Yes, since it then uses the ‘normal’ small caps font.

Comment: I guess this is fine for me, but what is the purpose of the first `\bfseries`?

Comment: The second argument of `\xpatchcmd` is the original code which is to be replaced with the third argument.

Comment: Ok thank you, this is a great solution. Last question: How can I remove the pagenumber of this single page?

Comment: As it might be useful to others, I've added the line of code which does it in an edit.